# Run terminal command with NSTask

Tags: objective-c, nstask

I want to run a Terminal command in my program.
The command looks like this:

```
cd /path/to/file/; ./foo HTTPProxy 127.0.0.1
```

It works with `system()` but it doesn't work when I use `NSTask`.

```
system("cd /path/to/file/; ./foo HTTPProxy 127.0.0.1");
```

works fine but

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/path/to/file/./foo"];

NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput:pipe];
NSFileHandle *file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"HTTPProxy 127.0.0.1", nil]];
[task launch];

NSData *data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(string);
```

doesn't. 
Output:

```
Command-line option 'HTTPProxy 127.0.0.1' with no value. Failing.
```

Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I think I have got it:

```
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"HTTPProxy", @"127.0.0.1", nil]];
```

those are separate arguments in your invocation from the command line...

OLD ANSWER:

You could trying setting the current directory for execution:

```
– setCurrentDirectoryPath:
```

This is basically the effect of `cd` in the `system` version of your code.